# How to find the number of distinct sub strings of n strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, distinct-values, substring, string-algorithm

Given n strings each of `length <=10^5`.

Input: `“aa ab ac ad”`

Output: `8` `(“a”,”b”,”c”,”d”,”aa”,”ab”,”ac”,”ad”)`

Input: `“aab bcd”`

Output: `10` `(“a”,”b”,”c”,”d”,”aa”,”ab”,”bc”,”cd”,”aab”,”bcd”)`

**update:**

suffix tree is one solution.But it takes more memory.

Is there any solution other than suffix tree?

Comment: First of all: Which language and what did you try so far?

Comment: no matter of language. i want approach/algorithm

Comment: Did you try to come up with one on your own yet?

Comment: i tried but did't get any idea

Comment: Doing a simple google search should give you easily the answer : https://www.quora.com/Given-a-string-how-do-I-find-the-number-of-distinct-substrings-of-the-string

Comment: Read question properly i am not asking for one string@Damien Prot

Answer (score 0):

Suffix tree. You don't need to do anything other than set the suffix tree up, it is precisely a structure that lists all the distinct sub-strings of any string or set of strings.

Comment: but it requires lot of space when the n value is large